# Minimum eigenvalue of normal matrix with polynomial basis

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, polynomials, least-squares

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, let $x_n(t)=\frac{t^n}{n!}$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. As the set of functions $X_N=(x_0 ,\ldots, x_N)$ are linearly independent, the matrix
$
\int_0^1 X_N(t)^\top X_N(t)\,\mathrm{d} t$ is positive definite.

Is it possible to quantify the behavior (such as lower bound) of the minimum eigenvalue in terms of $N$?

Comment: An "obvious" upper bound is the bottom right entry $\frac1{N!^2(N+1)}$, but numerical experiments indicate the correct order probably has another factorial.